# Rails find_or_create_by add cast to hash value json type attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, hash, casting

I have a model with an `:extra_fields` column that is `:jsonb` datatype, I want to add in the attr hashes to the column, something like this below but I am unsure of the syntax to cast the hash values' datatypes here, and if not here what is the best practice for casting hash value data ?

```
      instance = Model.find_or_create_by(ref_id: hash[:ref_id]) do |a|
          a.extra_fields = {

            'attr1' : hash[:attr1], <-- //possible to cast type here ie ::type ?
            'attr2' : hash[:attr2]  <--

          }
        instance.save!
      end
```

Bonus: how would I cast the hash values as type `:decimal`, `:string`, `:boolean`, `:date` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All incoming parameters in Rails/Rack are strings. Well except except array/hash parameters which still have strings as values. Rails does the actual casting when you pass parameters to models.

You can cast strings to any other type in Ruby with the `.to_x` methods:

```
irb(main):006:0> "1.23".to_f
=> 1.23
irb(main):007:0> "1.23".to_d
=> #<BigDecimal:7ff7dea40b68,'0.123E1',18(18)>
irb(main):008:0> 1.23.to_s
=> "1.23"
irb(main):008:0> 1.23.to_i
=> 1
```

Boolean casting is a Rails feature. You can do it by:

```
# Rails 5
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value) 
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast("true") # true
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast("t") # true 
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast("false") # false
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast("f") # false
# This is somewhat surprising
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast("any arbitrary string") # true


# Rails 4.2
ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_database(value)

# Rails 4.1 and below
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(value)
```

Note that this is very different then the Ruby boolean coercion done by `!` and `!!`.

```
irb(main):008:0> !!"false"
(irb):8: warning: string literal in condition
=> true
```

In Ruby everything except nil and false are true.

Dates are somewhat more complex. The default Rails date inputs use multi-parameters to send each part of the date (year, month, day) and a special setter that constructs a date from these inputs.

```
Processing by PeopleController#create as HTML
  Parameters: { "person"=>{"birthday(1i)"=>"2019", "birthday(2i)"=>"2", "birthday(3i)"=>"16"}, ...}
```

You can construct a date from these parameters by:

```
date_params = params.fetch(:person).permit("birthday")
Date.new(*date_params.values.map(&:to_i))
```

> what is the best practice for casting hash value data ?

There is no best practice here. What you instead should be pondering is the use of a JSON column. Since you seem to be want to apply some sort of schema to the data it might be a good idea to actually create a separate table and model. You are after all using a relational database.

JSON columns are great for solving some complex issues like key/value tables or storing raw JSON data but they should not be your first choice when modelling your data.

See [PostgreSQL anti-patterns: Unnecessary json/hstore dynamic columns](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/) for a good write up on the topic.